# Trying to test vertical stepper. How do I find the 'Property' text on the screen when the debug output doesn't have the 'Property' text?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have this vertical stepper that looks like this.
[image]

```
function VerticalStepperComponent(props) {
  const { steps, activeStep, hidden, className } = props;

  return (
    <Wrapper className={className}>
      <ChildrenWrapper>
        {props.children}
      </ChildrenWrapper>

      <StepperWrapper hidden={hidden}>
        <StyledStepper
          activeStep={activeStep}
          orientation="vertical"
          connector={<ss.QontoConnectorV2 />}
          data-testid="vertical-stepper"
        >
          {steps?.map((label) => ( 
            <Step key={label}>
              <ss.StepperLabel StepIconComponent={QontoStepIcon} data-testid="stepper-label">
                {label}
              </ss.StepperLabel>
            </Step>
          ))}
        </StyledStepper>
      </StepperWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    steps: appSelectors.steps(state),
  }
}

export const VerticalStepper = connect(mapStateToProps)(VerticalStepperComponent);
```

I want to test that the property component is checked so first I try to find the DOM node. But when I try `screen.getByText(/Property/i)`, it says unable to find element

So I was trying to figure out why its not rendering the element. So I did

```
const verticalStepper = screen.getByTestId('vertical-stepper');
 screen.debug(verticalStepper);
```

to see the DOM structure.  The result was just this

```
<div
      class="MuiPaper-root MuiStepper-root MuiStepper-vertical sc-iwyYcG chxTQc MuiPaper-elevation0"
      data-testid="vertical-stepper"
/>
```

It seems like its not rendering VerticalStepper properly, since 'Property' and 'Permit Holder' don't show up in the DOM structure. I feel like the problem is that VerticalStepper is a redux connected component. https://slawkolodziej.com/posts/guide-testing-redux-connected-components-with-react-testing-library-and-jest

How do I find the node that displays 'Property'